# How to assign an array of characters to a string literal

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, string-literals

I have an array of char and I'm trying to have a string literal with the same chars in the array.

I tried strcpy, and try =, and I tried what I did in the following code. But it doesn't seem to work or I'm understanding something.

```
char s1[10]="Youssef";
char *s2
while(*s2!='\0')
    *s2++=*s1++;
printf("%s",s2);
```

Process doesn't return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals are read only.

In any case, what you are trying to do seems you are confused.

A string literal: `char *sl = "string literal";`

An uninitialized char pointer: `char *s2;`

In order to do the copy you like, you first need to allocate memory for the string.

Moreover, you cannot do pointer arithmetics with an array. Arrays and pointers are *not* the same thing!

Furthermore, you should remember the origin of `s2` pointer, since after incrementing it until the copy is complete, you would then need to reset the pointer.. Exercise: Think what would happen if you did the copy in a function (preferably named mystrcpy`)...

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char s1[10]="Youssef";
  char *s2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s1) + 1)); // +1 for the NULL-terminator
  int i = 0;
  char *origin_s2 = s2;
  while(s1[i] != '\0')
    *s2++ = s1[i++];
  *s2 = '\0';
  s2 = origin_s2;
  printf("%s\n", s2);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Youssef

PS: It is highly recommended to check if the dynamic allocation of the memory was successful (check if return value of `malloc()` is not `NULL`).

Comment: or can I use something like:
    char s1[10]="Testing";
    char *s2;
    s2=strtok(s1,"");
    printf("%s",s2);
    return 0;

Comment: Sure you can @YoussefHussein, but that's not copying, that's having `s2` pointer point to the memory that the array has stored the string . . .

Comment: "Can't do pointer arithmetic with an array"? Since when? `*(a+1)` works just as well as `a[1]` for both arrays and pointers.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: `*(a+1)` does not do pointer arithmetic on an array. If `a` is an array, it is converted to a pointer before the arithmetic. But the context for the question is `*s1++`, where `s1` is an array. In that case, `++` cannot be applied to `s1` since it requires an lvalue, and the result of `s1` after conversion to a pointer is a value. So it is indeed true that `++` cannot be applied to an array.

Comment: I would say "you can't change the value of an array variable".

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally answered my question. I'm sorry but is there another way to do it using strcpy? After allocating the memory ofcourse just like you did.

Comment: @YoussefHussein, sure! Check the example in the [online documentation of strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)